# JQuery selector in handmade lightbox issue + live demo. Simple script need help :)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, selector, lightbox

I have a problem with JQuery. In theory I wanted to do some sort of Lighbox / popout with a form mail. But the problem is: I can't use the form because of starting the function to hide the Lighbox. I do not know if I can explain this and I have attached a small demo below.

[<------------ Link of the Demo ------------>](http://contat.eu/varie/problems/)

Sorry for the bad English. I am good at understanding ... in the grammar but I pretty much suck.

Comment: Hi, if there is anyone willing to help me I will be online for 2 hours from now. Thanks, from Italy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your scripts:

```
$('.blackover form').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();});
```

It will prevent the click-event of the form from bubbling upwards to the parent `section`-element

Comment: I am new in javascript (I'm 17 and I confess study-mail). but how do you know all these details. Mah! Ingenious! Thank you!